# How can I filter on multiple values or wildcard in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, filter

I am trying to filter a key on various strings.  I can filter on one fixed string like this:

```
(filter #(= (:TEST_KEY %) "TEST: 1")records)
```

While that works, I need to be able to also include "`TEST: 2"` and `"TEST: ABC"`.  How can I get the filter to work on multiple values?  Is there a way to filter on a wildcard like `"TEST: *"` that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michiel Borkent's answer covers the wildcard case. Where there is an enumerated set of options clojure allows the use of a literal set as a function which tests for membership. This can be used idiomatically with `filter` (because all values other than nil or false in clojure are truthy).

```
user> (#{"A" "B"} "A")
;;=> "A"
user> (#{"A" "B"} "C")
;;=> nil
```

I use `comp` to create a function that first looks up the key in the record and then tests it with a set:

```
(filter (comp #{"TEST: 1" "TEST: 2" "TEST: ABC"} :TEST_KEY) records)
```

Note that the `#{}` syntax above is a set literal and has nothing to do with the `#()` anonymous function syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
(filter #(.startsWith (:TEST_KEY % "") "TEST: ")      
        [{:TEST_KEY "TEST: 1"} {:TEST_KEY "TEST: 2"} {:NONSENSE "foo"}])

;; or equivalently

(filter #(re-find #"TEST: .*"        ;; use regular expression to match
                  (:TEST_KEY % ""))  ;; get value of :TEST_KEY, 
                                     ;; use empty string as default 
        [{:TEST_KEY "TEST: 1"} {:TEST_KEY "TEST: 2"} {:NONSENSE "foo"}])
;;=> ({:TEST_KEY "TEST: 1"} {:TEST_KEY "TEST: 2"})
```